# Prestashop webapi reset mysql cache by Web API or call SQL by Presta Web Service API

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, prestashop-1.7

Hi i have problem with Presta WebService. I'm using prestashop with node (nestJS). I Created a connection with MySql database (Presta DB) with SSH tunelling. It works corectly, i can do any query, and SQL returns "OK statuses". I checked it by ssh client, (queries in temrinal) and data is updated in DB. Problem is when i want to select this data by PrestaWebService, when i pick data presta returns "old" propably cached data. On presta Admin i have ceching "off". After manually reset cache by admin panel button keep presta returns me 'old" data. Anyone know whats going on? :D

Comment: You really should ask this question on PrestaShop's support forum as this seems to be an operational / configuration problem, not a programming one. SO is a programming Q/A site. If you think this is a programming question, pls share the relevant code with us along with debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. I used incorrect table. I queried ps_product but should ps_product_shop.